# contenation of strings in php

Tags: php, concatenation, string-concatenation

I want to concatenate of multiple strings with condition

I am doing a loadmore in ajax and php and i want to dynamic the response, so i have tried below code

```php
$newList .= '<ul>';
$newList .= '<li>';
$newList .= '<i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>';
$newList .= $this->Common_model->startend_date_format($getEvent['event_stat'], $getEvent['event_end']);
$newList .= '</li>';
$newList .= '<li>';
$newList .= '<i class="fa fa-map-marked"></i>';
if ($city != "") {
    $newList .= '<a href=' . base_url() . 'city/' . $this->Common_model->makeSeoUrl($city) . '>' . ucfirst($city) . '</a>, &nbsp;' ;
}                    
if ($state != "") {
    $newList .= '<a href="' . base_url() . 'state/' . $this->Common_model->makeSeoUrl($state) . '>' . ucfirst($state) . '</a>, &nbsp';
}
if ($get_country_name != "") {
    $newList .= '<a href=' . base_url() . 'country/' . $this->Common_model->makeSeoUrl($get_country_name) . '/' . base64_encode($get_country_id) . '>' . ucfirst($get_country_name) . '</a>';
}
$newList .= '</li>';
$newList .= '<li>';
$newList .= '<i class="fa fa-tags"></i>';
$newList .= '<a href=' . base_url() . 'categories' . '#' . $cat_name_event . '>' . $cat_name_event . '</a>';
$newList .= '</li>';
$newList .= '</ul>';
```

and it is showing something like

[image: tried concatenation]

but the actual result should be like

[image: actual concatenation]

Comment: All of the values of your `href` should be in some form of quotes.

Comment: According to the code you posted i would say it is ok. In your code i see the calendar class which is displayed for you with start and end date. I can also see the city/state/country which are also displayed like you say. The only part missing is the categories but that error is 99.99% coming from php so we need the backend code.